# Magento 2.3.1 UI Component Dynamic Rows, "Is Default" is not getting saved

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.3.1, default, dynamic-rows, extrafee

I have created a dynamic form using Dynamic Rows in UI component form as shown in following screenshot:

[image]

Following is my code samples for your reference:

> Namespace\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\ui_component\form.xml

```
<fieldset name="fee_options_container" component="Magento_Catalog/js/components/visible-on-option/fieldset"
          sortOrder="15">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="select" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Manage Options</label>
    </settings>
    <dynamicRows name="fee_options">
        <settings>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Option</addButtonLabel>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
        </settings>
        <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="is_default" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/checkbox" sortOrder="0"
                   formElement="checkbox">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="inputCheckBoxName" xsi:type="string">default</item>
                        <item name="columnsHeaderClasses" xsi:type="string">control-table-options-th</item>
                        <item name="modules" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="rows" xsi:type="string">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = fee_options</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <additionalClasses>
                        <class name="control-table-options-cell">true</class>
                    </additionalClasses>
                    <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Is Default</label>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <checkbox>
                        <settings>
                            <prefer>radio</prefer>
                        </settings>
                    </checkbox>
                </formElements>
            </field>
            <field name="fee_price" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input"
                   template="Magento_Catalog/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">fee_price.value</item>
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="suffixName" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Price</label>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <field name="fee_type" formElement="select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">fee_type.value</item>
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Apply As</label>
                    <dataScope>fee_type</dataScope>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="Magedelight\AdditionalFee\Model\Rule\Action\ActionProvider"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
            <field name="store_0" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input"
                   template="Magento_Catalog/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Admin</label>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <field name="position" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">position.order</item>
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <visible>false</visible>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <actionDelete name="action_delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">fee.delete</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <elementTmpl>Magento_Catalog/form/element/action-delete</elementTmpl>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <componentType>actionDelete</componentType>
                </settings>
            </actionDelete>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
</fieldset>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save.php

```
public function execute() {
   $dynamicRowData = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
}
```

> Response of $dynamicRowData:

```
Array
(
    [fee_id] => 4
    [fee_name] => test
    [display_type] => checkbox
    [fee_options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [store_1] => test 1
                    [store_2] => test 1
                    [fee_type] => F
                    [record_id] => 0
                    [fee_price] => 10
                    [store_0] => test 1
                    [position] => 1
                    [initialize] => true
                    [is_default] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [record_id] => 1
                    [store_1] => test 2
                    [store_2] => test 2
                    [fee_price] => 20
                    [fee_type] => F
                    [store_0] => test 2
                    [position] => 2
                    [initialize] => true
                    [is_default] => 0
                )

        )

    [default] => Array
        (
            [0] => option_0
        )

    [fee_price] => Array
        (
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [option_0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                        )

                    [option_1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20
                        )

                )

        )

    [option_0] => test 1
    [option_1] => test 2
    [position] => Array
        (
            [order] => Array
                (
                    [option_0] => 1
                    [option_1] => 2
                )

        )

    [form_key] => 4Nj0oUjsJRfKgtWo
```

I'm saving `is_default` value like follows:

```
if (isset($data['is_default'])) {
    foreach ($dynamicRowData as $recId => $record) {
        if ($recId == $data['is_default']) {
            $dynamicRowData[$recId]['is_default'] = 1;
        }
        else {
            $dynamicRowData[$recId]['is_default'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

On edit page if I print Dataprovider's data, I'm getting following array for `fee_options`:

```
[fee_options] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [store_1] => test 1
            [store_2] => test 1
            [fee_type] => F
            [record_id] => 0
            [fee_price] => 10
            [store_0] => test 1
            [position] => 1
            [initialize] => true
            [is_default] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [record_id] => 1
            [store_1] => test 2
            [store_2] => test 2
            [fee_price] => 20
            [fee_type] => F
            [store_0] => test 2
            [position] => 2
            [initialize] => true
            [is_default] => 0
        )
)
```

I can't save "is_default" field value, how can I make it selected at the time of Edit form. Can anyone please let me know if I'm missing anything? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: please attach the data of $this->getRequest()->getParams();

Comment: @RkRathod Response of $this->getRequest()->getParams() added in question.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: check condition under the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
 $dynamicRowData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('fee_options');

 foreach($dynamicRowData as $data)
 {
    if($data['is_default'] == 0)
    {
            //save is_default value
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not working. I have added more details. Please check.

Comment: any error ??????

Comment: Not getting any error, my form gets saved without selected default value.